# Upgrade from Docker 1.08 to 1.10

Tags: docker

I need to upgrade my current Docker version which is 1.8.2-fc22 to 1.10.0 or newer.
From the Docker docs I've executed:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker run --rm -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker docker/v1.10-migrator
```

The output is:

```
time="2016-10-21T14:25:10Z" level=error msg="Can't initialize device mapper: \"driver not supported\""
```

Any help ? Should I update my Fedora (21) first ?
My system specs:
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64+debug #1 SMP Fri Jun 24 21:06:28 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Why only to 1.10? The most recent version of docker is 1.12.

Comment: My requirement is a system which at least Docker 1.10. Besides it, I couldn't find an equivalent v.1.12-migrator

Comment: This is something you would upgrade with your package manager, likely dnf if you're using Fedora. I would follow the instructions in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/fedora/).